# Add Button to enter full screen mode SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a basic video player and I'm wondering how I can create a custom button to enter full screen mode for the video player. I'd like to set `controller.showsPlaybackControls to` false`and add in my custom controls. Other than using`controller.showsPlaybackControls = true`, I'm not sure how to get a custom full screen button.

Note the video Player will be nested in a scroll view with other elements around it. It will also not have access to the full width of the screen.

```swift
struct HustleVideoPlayerR: View {
    let url: URL
    @State var player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
    @State var value: Float = 0
    @State var viewID = false
    @State var aspect: CGSize = CGSize(width: 16, height: 9)
    @State private var currentTime: Double = 0.0
    @State private var totalLength: Double = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: $player, showControls: true)
            .id(viewID)
            .aspectRatio(aspect, contentMode: .fit)
            .background(Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
            .onAppear {
                player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                viewID.toggle()
                
                Task {
                    do {
                        if let final = try await getVideoResolution(url: url.absoluteString) {
                            self.aspect = final
                        }
                    } catch { }
                }
            }
            .onDisappear {
                self.player.pause()
                player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
                viewID.toggle()
            }
    }
}

struct VideoPlayer : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var player : AVPlayer
    let showControls: Bool
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayer>) -> AVPlayerViewController {

        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = showControls
        controller.allowsVideoFrameAnalysis = false
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayer>) { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your requirement to toggle full-screen mode for a video player within a [SwiftUI view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view), using [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit) components is indeed necessary due to the nature of [`UIViewControllerRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable).
However, as you have pointed out, simply toggling [`showsPlaybackControls`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller/1615824-showsplaybackcontrols) does not achieve entering or exiting full-screen mode directly.

First, make sure your [`VideoPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/videoplayer) struct can communicate with the `HustleVideoPlayerR` view to toggle full-screen. Since [`AVPlayerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller) does not offer a direct method to enter full-screen, the common workaround is manipulating the view hierarchy and presentation styles or using a coordinator to handle button actions.

- Place a UIButton in the AVPlayerViewController's view as suggested. That button will serve as the trigger for entering and exiting full-screen mode.
- Use a coordinator within your `UIViewControllerRepresentable` to handle button taps, allowing you to execute more complex logic than simply toggling playback controls.
- Since you cannot directly toggle full-screen mode, simulate it by adjusting the player's view size and constraints to fill the entire screen. That can involve presenting a new view controller that only contains the video player in full-screen or adjusting the current view controller's view hierarchy.

```swift
struct VideoPlayer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var player: AVPlayer
    var onTapFullScreen: () -> Void
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, onTapFullScreen: onTapFullScreen)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        
        // Custom button setup
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Full Screen", for: .normal)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 50)
        button.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        controller.view.addSubview(button)
        
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) { }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var parent: VideoPlayer
        var onTapFullScreen: () -> Void
        
        init(_ player: VideoPlayer, onTapFullScreen: @escaping () -> Void) {
            self.parent = player
            self.onTapFullScreen = onTapFullScreen
        }
        
        @objc func buttonTapped() {
            onTapFullScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

In your SwiftUI view (`HustleVideoPlayerR`), when defining the `VideoPlayer`, provide a closure for `onTapFullScreen` that manipulates the view to achieve a full-screen effect. That might involve using a full-screen modal presentation or dynamically adjusting view constraints.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a way to use apples default in screen mode. If I turn playbackcontrols on then the available full screen button has to execute some logic, im wondering what logic it runs so that the video is presented in fullscreen.

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower OK. Note that replicating the exact behavior of Apple's full-screen transition without using the provided button is challenging because you do not have access to the internals of how `AVPlayerViewController` manages its full-screen state. However, if you want to trigger full-screen mode programmatically while still using `AVPlayerViewController`'s playback controls (and thus its full-screen button), the simplest approach is to enable the default playback controls (`controller.showsPlaybackControls = true`) and allow the user to use the built-in full-screen button.

Comment: Ok thanks. Looking at how discord does this I think they use your approach. But instead of modifying the frame of the same video player they pass the video player to the top of the view hierarchy. And then present the passed video player above everything. And they probably use a geometry effect to transition this. I’ll probably stick to this approach.

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower Great! Don't hesitate to post your own answer if you manage to make it work.

Comment: The link you posted above is invalid @JaxonSteinhower

Comment: Sorry here it is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78026180/swift-ui-adding-background-color-to-text-element-fails/78026415#78026415

Comment: We were not able to figure out the answer in that link above. Its not an important question at all but it's a pretty interesting UI challenge with manipulating strings if you want to give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use UIKit component for your goal, because you are using `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

you can put this code inside of `makeUIViewController`

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system)

button.setTitle("Tap me", for: .normal)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 50)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

controller.view.addSubview(button)
```

———

```
@objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    controller.showsPlaybackControl = false
}
```

———

Eventually, you'll need a `Coordinator` if changing the value of `controller.showsPlaybackControl` doesn't work.

Comment: For action, you can also use callback. e.g. `let onTapButton: () -> Void` in `VideoPlayer`, and `func doSomething() {}` in `HustleVideoPlayerR`. Then you can use like this `VideoPlayer(player: $player, showControls: true, onTapButton: { doSomething() })`. And also don't forget to put `onTapButton()` inside `@objc func buttonTapped`

Comment: Ok, I just had the time to glance at your code and it seems like the button you have only modifies **controller.showsPlaybackControl**. As my question said I want a custom button that will enter full screen mode and exit full screen mode. Changing **controller.showsPlaybackControl** doesn't do that.