# Adding background color to text element fails

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a complex struct in swift ui that detects links and hashtags inside of strings. The struct modifies their colors and detects clicks on specific hashtags and links. I would like to add a background color to the hashtags specifically and some padding. Currently hashtags are purple and bold. I'd like the final look to a white hashtag with a purple background. When I try to apply the padding and background modifiers to the Text element I get the error below.

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'some View' to return type 'Text'

I will provide the complete code in order to make this question reproducible. But note that the relevant code is inside of **LinkColoredText**. This is the first structure so you won't have to scroll through everything.

The problem lies in the fact that these views in the body are elements inside the components array and adding padding or a background color will cause a mismatching type.

```
import SwiftUI

private let linkDetector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)

struct LinkColoredText: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    enum Component {
        case text(String)
        case link(String, URL)
        case hashtag(String, String)
    }

    let text: String
    let components: [Component]

    init(text: String, links: [NSTextCheckingResult], hashtags: [String]) {
        self.text = text
        let nsText = text as NSString

        var components: [Component] = []
        var index = 0
        for result in links {
            if result.range.location > index {
                
                let sub_str = nsText.substring(with: NSRange(location: index, length: result.range.location - index))
                
                if findHashtags(in: sub_str).isEmpty {
                    components.append(.text(nsText.substring(with: NSRange(location: index, length: result.range.location - index))))
                } else {
                    let words = extractWordsAndSpaces(from: sub_str)
                    var offset = 0
                    for word in words {
                        if !findHashtags(in: String(word)).isEmpty && containsWhiteSpace(at: offset - 1, in: sub_str) {
                            components.append(.hashtag(nsText.substring(with: NSRange(location: index + offset, length: word.count)), String(word)))
                        } else {
                            components.append(.text(nsText.substring(with: NSRange(location: index + offset, length: word.count))))
                        }
                        offset += word.count
                    }
                }
            }
            components.append(.link(nsText.substring(with: result.range), result.url!))
            index = result.range.location + result.range.length
        }
        if index < nsText.length {
            let sub_str = nsText.substring(from: index)
            var offset = 0
            
            if findHashtags(in: sub_str).isEmpty {
                components.append(.text(sub_str))
            } else {
                let words = extractWordsAndSpaces(from: sub_str)

                for word in words {
                    if !findHashtags(in: String(word)).isEmpty && containsWhiteSpace(at: offset - 1, in: sub_str){
                        components.append(.hashtag(nsText.substring(with: NSRange(location: index + offset, length: word.count)), String(word)))
                        
                    } else {
                        components.append(.text(nsText.substring(with: NSRange(location: index + offset, length: word.count))))
                    }
                    offset += word.count
                }
            }
        }
        self.components = components
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        components.map { component in
            switch component {
            case .text(let text):
                return Text(verbatim: text)
            case .link(let text, _):
                return Text(verbatim: text)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            case .hashtag(let text, _):
                return Text(verbatim: text)
                    .foregroundColor(.indigo).bold()
            }
        }.reduce(Text(""), +)
    }
}

struct LinkedText: View {
    let text: String
    let istip: Bool
    let isMessage: Bool?
    let links: [NSTextCheckingResult]
    let hashtags: [String]
    
    init (_ text: String, tip: Bool, isMess: Bool?) {
        self.text = text
        self.istip = tip
        self.isMessage = isMess
        let nsText = text as NSString
        let wholeString = NSRange(location: 0, length: nsText.length)
        links = linkDetector.matches(in: text, options: [], range: wholeString)
        hashtags = findHashtags(in: text)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        LinkColoredText(text: text, links: links, hashtags: hashtags)
            .overlay(LinkTapOverlay(text: text, isTip: istip, isMessage: isMessage, links: links, hashtags: hashtags))
    }
}

private struct LinkTapOverlay: UIViewRepresentable {
    let text: String
    let isTip: Bool
    let isMessage: Bool?
    let links: [NSTextCheckingResult]
    let hashtags: [String]
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> LinkTapOverlayView {
        let view = LinkTapOverlayView(frame: .zero, text: text, overlay: self)
        view.textContainer = context.coordinator.textContainer

        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.didTapLabel(_:)))
        tapGesture.delegate = context.coordinator
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.didLongPressLabel(_:)))
        longPressGesture.delegate = context.coordinator
        view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)

        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: LinkTapOverlayView, context: Context) {
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)])
        context.coordinator.textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attributedString)
        context.coordinator.textStorage!.addLayoutManager(context.coordinator.layoutManager)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
        let overlay: LinkTapOverlay

        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: .zero)
        var textStorage: NSTextStorage?
        
        init(_ overlay: LinkTapOverlay) {
            self.overlay = overlay
            
            textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
            textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0
            layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        }

        @objc func didTapLabel(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            let location = gesture.location(in: gesture.view!)
            if let result = link(at: location) {
                guard let url = result.url else {
                    return
                }
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else if let result = hashtag(at: location) {
                
            }
        }
        
        @objc func didLongPressLabel(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
            if gesture.state == .began {

            }
        }

        private func link(at point: CGPoint) -> NSTextCheckingResult? {
            guard !overlay.links.isEmpty else {
                return nil
            }
            let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(
                for: point,
                in: textContainer,
                fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil
            )

            for i in 0..<overlay.links.count {
                if indexOfCharacter >= overlay.links[i].range.location && indexOfCharacter <= (overlay.links[i].range.location + overlay.links[i].range.length) {
                    return overlay.links[i]
                }
            }
            
            return nil
        }
        
        private func hashtag(at point: CGPoint) -> String? {
            guard !overlay.hashtags.isEmpty else {
                return nil
            }
            let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(
                for: point,
                in: textContainer,
                fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil
            )
            let words = extractWordsAndSpaces(from: overlay.text)
            var offset = 0

            for i in 0..<words.count {
                if indexOfCharacter >= offset && indexOfCharacter <= (offset + words[i].count){
                    if !findHashtags(in: words[i]).isEmpty {
                        if i == 0 {
                            return words[i]
                        } else if words[i - 1].hasSuffix(" "){
                            return words[i]
                        }
                    }
                    return nil
                }
                offset += words[i].count
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}

private class LinkTapOverlayView: UIView {
    private var overlay: LinkTapOverlay?
    var textContainer: NSTextContainer!
    var text: String?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didLongPressLabel(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    convenience init(frame: CGRect, text: String, overlay: LinkTapOverlay) {
        self.init(frame: frame)
        self.text = text
        self.overlay = overlay
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        var newSize = bounds.size
        newSize.height += 20
        textContainer.size = newSize
    }

    @objc func didLongPressLabel(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.state == .began {

        }
    }
}

func findHashtags(in text: String) -> [String] {
   do {
       let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "#\\w+", options: [])
       let matches = regex.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count))
       return matches.map {
           String(text[Range($0.range, in: text)!])
       }
   } catch {
       return []
   }
}

func extractWordsAndSpaces(from sentence: String) -> [String] {
    let pattern = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\S+|\\s+", options: [])

    let matches = pattern.matches(in: sentence, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: sentence.utf16.count))

    let resultArray = matches.map { (match) -> String in
        let range = Range(match.range, in: sentence)!
        return String(sentence[range])
    }
    return resultArray
}

func containsWhiteSpace(at index: Int, in text: String) -> Bool {
    if index == -1 {
        return true
    }
    guard index >= 0 && index < text.count else {
        return false
    }

    let charAtIndex = text[text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: index)]
    return charAtIndex.isWhitespace
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue should be because you are trying to mix `Text` views with modifiers that change their return type to `some View`, which no longer matches the expected return type of `Text` element.

Instead of using of a `@State` dictionary to store measurements and offsets for hashtag backgrounds, calculated dynamically ([MatBuompy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12989363/matbuompy)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78026415/6309)), you could try directly modifying the `LinkColoredText` struct to use a [`ForEach`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach) to iterate over the components and apply styles conditionally within the SwiftUI view hierarchy.

That would preserve the styling within the confines of SwiftUI's declarative nature, making sure that each component is styled according to its type *without* requiring additional state management or calculations outside the SwiftUI view updates.

```swift
struct LinkColoredText: View {
    // Existing properties

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(Array(components.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, component in
                Group {
                    switch component {
                    case .text(let text):
                        Text(verbatim: text)
                    case .link(let text, _):
                        Text(verbatim: text)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    case .hashtag(let text, _):
                        Text(verbatim: text)
                            .bold()
                            .padding(4) // Adjust padding as needed
                            .background(Color.purple) // Background color for hashtag
                            .foregroundColor(.white) // Text color for hashtag
                            .cornerRadius(5) // Optional: Adjust corner radius as needed
                    }
                }
            }
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    }
}
```

By wrapping the [`Text`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text) elements inside a [`Group`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/group) within a [`HStack`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/hstack), you can maintain inline display of the text components while applying specific modifications to each component.
That allows you to iterate over the components with their indices, which is necessary for using them in a `ForEach` loop for SwiftUI to maintain state properly.
The `.hashtag` case applies padding, background color, and text color directly to the `Text` view. That should give you the desired look for hashtags with a purple background and white text.

Comment: Great thanks. This causes a new problem since the sub views are sometimes bigger than the space available in an HStack. The solution to this new problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78038734/swift-ui-layout-protocol-not-functioning-properly

Comment: I guess is my turn now to upvote you @VonC!

Answer (score 0):

This has been quite the challenge mate. The solution I've found involeves a `Dictionary` where the **keys** are all the hashtags present in the text String, and the **value** is another Dictionary where you store all the properties to apply to the **background View** or whatever customisation you want to apply. These calculations happen in the `onAppear` of the `LinkColoredText`.

But to the code first:

```
struct LinkColoredText: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    enum Component {
        case text(String)
        case link(String, URL)
        case hashtag(String, String)
    }
    
    let text: String
    let components: [Component]
    
    @State private var hashtagMap: [String: [String: CGFloat]] = [:]
    
    init(text: String, links: [NSTextCheckingResult], hashtags: [String]) {
        self.text = text
        let nsText = text as NSString
        
        var components: [Component] = []
        var index = 0
        for result in links {
            if result.range.location > index {
                
                let sub_str = nsText.substring(with: NSRange(location: index, length: result.range.location - index))
                
                if findHashtags(in: sub_str).isEmpty {
                    components.append(.text(nsText.substring(with: NSRange(location: index, length: result.range.location - index))))
                } else {
                    let words = extractWordsAndSpaces(from: sub_str)
                    var offset = 0
                    for word in words {
                        if !findHashtags(in: String(word)).isEmpty && containsWhiteSpace(at: offset - 1, in: sub_str) {
                            components.append(.hashtag(nsText.substring(with: NSRange(location: index + offset, length: word.count)), String(word)))
                        } else {
                            components.append(.text(nsText.substring(with: NSRange(location: index + offset, length: word.count))))
                        }
                        offset += word.count
                    }
                }
            }
            components.append(.link(nsText.substring(with: result.range), result.url!))
            index = result.range.location + result.range.length
        }
        if index < nsText.length {
            let sub_str = nsText.substring(from: index)
            var offset = 0
            
            if findHashtags(in: sub_str).isEmpty {
                components.append(.text(sub_str))
            } else {
                let words = extractWordsAndSpaces(from: sub_str)
                
                for word in words {
                    if !findHashtags(in: String(word)).isEmpty && containsWhiteSpace(at: offset - 1, in: sub_str){
                        components.append(.hashtag(nsText.substring(with: NSRange(location: index + offset, length: word.count)), String(word)))
                        
                    } else {
                        components.append(.text(nsText.substring(with: NSRange(location: index + offset, length: word.count))))
                    }
                    offset += word.count
                }
            }
        }
        self.components = components
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            components.map { component in
                switch component {
                case .text(let text):
                    return Text(verbatim: text)
                case .link(let text, _):
                    return Text(verbatim: text)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                case .hashtag(let text, _):
                    return Text(verbatim: text)
                        .foregroundColor(.indigo).bold()
                }
            }.reduce(Text(""), +)
        }
        .background(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                /// You must use sorted(by: <) otherwise the background won't always appear because the last could be placed before the first
                ForEach(Array(hashtagMap.keys.sorted(by: <)), id: \.self) { word in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
                        .fill(.gray)
                        .frame(width: hashtagMap[word]!["backdroundWidth"] ?? 0)
                        .offset(x: hashtagMap[word]!["backgroundOffset"] ?? 0)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            let nsText = text as NSString
            let tokenizedText = text.components(separatedBy: " ")
            let index = 0
            if index < nsText.length {
                let sub_str = nsText.substring(from: index)
                let offset = 0
                let words = extractWordsAndSpaces(from: sub_str)
                for word in words {
                    if !findHashtags(in: String(word)).isEmpty && containsWhiteSpace(at: offset - 1, in: sub_str){
                        let indexOfWord = tokenizedText.firstIndex(of: word) ?? 0
                        var letters = 0
                        for i in 0...indexOfWord {
                            letters += tokenizedText[i].count
                        }
                        
                        /// 4.6 is the width of each letter. I've chosen this myself based on my testings
                        hashtagMap[word] = ["backgroundOffset": CGFloat(Double(letters) * 4),
                                            "backdroundWidth": CGFloat(10 * word.count)]
                        print("Offset \(indexOfWord)")
                        print("Letters \(letters)")
                        print("Word \(word)")
                        print("Map \(hashtagMap)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Now, It is not perfect and has a lot of things to be fixed such as finding a better way to distantiate the backgrounds, finding the best width and when a line ends it should adjust the **y** of the offset too maybe.
The idea was to get you started and give you an idea on how to tackle this issue.

Here's the result:

[image: background to hashtag]

Let me know if this is what you were looking for!

Comment: This adds the effect to everything and not only hashtags. This doesnt work

Comment: Ok, I thought you wanted it to the entire View, sorry.

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower Have a look now. I've updated the code. It is not perfect but I think it could be good starting point.

Comment: Ok thanks. Im not sure this is the best approach. I thought about using offset but it is unreliable. Characters have different sizes for different fonts and different system settings. A simple bold modifier will mess it up. Can you think of a different approach. Maybe modifying the components array to be able to hold stuff like this.

Comment: It's a pretty complicated issue this one I must admit.

Comment: Maybe we could simulate the current hashtag Text behind the scenes and also the text before and after it in a separate fashion and calculate their widths using a GeometryReader? I don' t know if this could work but it is worth a shot I guess.

Comment: Thanks MatBuompy, VonC figured it out. Now to finish off the problem the final fix is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78038734/swift-ui-layout-protocol-not-functioning-properly

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower Guess I was just overcomplicating stuff mate, sorry for that.